# inheritance super() first statement in a constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, super

The below code displays the error `Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor`

```
    public class Vehicle {

private String type;
private int age;
private String model;
private float price;

public void vehicle(String type, int age, String model, float price){
    this.type = type;
    this.age = age;
    this.model = model;
    this.price = price;
    }
}
```

And Car class extends Vehicle;

```
public class Car extends Vehicle {

private int numberOfDoors;

public void car(String type, int age, String model, float price, int numberOfDoors){
    super(type, age, model, price); //Error:Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor
    this.numberOfDoors = numberOfDoors;
    }
}
```

Isn't it already first statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't it already first statement?

Yes.

But the message says:

> "Constructor call must be the first statement **in a constructor**."

... and `public void car(...)` is NOT a constructor for `Car`.  Rather, it is a method called `car` which has been declared as returning nothing.

Lessons:

1. A constructor's name must be identical to the name of the class.
2. A constructor never has a declared return type (or `void`).
3. If you ignore Java's identifier style rules, you are likely to shoot yourself in the foot.  A class name should ALWAYS start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: I got this, thanks! So i need this right?  "public Car(String type, int age, String model, float price, int numberOfDoors)"

Answer (score 2):

No.  The constructor of your class must be named "Car".  You have a method "car" (lower case), so `super` is not the first statement of a constructor.